# Shell script to kill process with highest PID

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to kill a specific java-process via a shell script.

I know that `kill -9 $(pidof java)` will kill it, yet it will also kill all other java processes. I know that the java-process I would like to kill is the one that was started as the last one.

So if I use `pidof java`, I will retrieve a set of PIDs, how can I assign that to a list (or sth similar) and the get the last element of it?

Thanks

Comment: Once the PID pool gets exhausted, it's restarted from 1. The latest process is in no way the one with the highest PID.

Comment: @choroba Thanks for the hint, I didn't think of that. But as the system is relatively small, not used a lot and restarted pretty frequently, I think the highest PID should be the latest process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am kind of a newbie for Shell scripts, but here is my solution:

```
kill -9 `ps aux | grep [j]ava | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -nr | head -n 1`
```

- `ps aux` prints the current processes
- `grep [j]ava` finds the processes containing "java" inside, except the current `grep` command
- `awk { print $2 }` retrieves the second column of `ps`, which is the pid
- `sort -nr` sorts the output by descending order (`n` is for numerical)
- `head -n 1` gets the first line of the sorted pids, which is the highest

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ps aux` instead of `ps -aux`?

Comment: Awesome, works fine! @damgad yes, you're right, when using `ps -aux`, I retrieved this warning: `Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html` (but it still worked). Thanks a lot.

Comment: `ps -aux` works well on my Fedora. My `ps` manpage says: `ps [-] [lujsvmaxScewhrnu] [txx] [O[+|-]k1[[+|-]k2...]] [pids]`, so the `-` seems to be optionnal